# Possible to register an app via API with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I've searched for a while all over to see if there is a way to register an app with Firebase via an API but cannot seem to find anything on the topic.

is it possible to register a bundle id with Firebase and then download the corresponding google-services.json and google-services.plist files?

I'm working on automating a repetitive process that I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brand new management API in beta that lets you programmatically create projects and add apps to them.  The documentation for that API is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/).  Specifically, you will want to look at [androidApps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.androidApps) and [iosApps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.iosApps) for creating and modifying apps on your project.